# Control.Invoke with input Parameters

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

From what I've found in C#, the Control.Invoke method requires that you use a delegate with no input parameters.  Is there any way around this?  I would like to invoke a method to update the UI from another thread and pass to string parameters to it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Which version of C# are you using? If you are using C#3.5 you can use closures to avoid passing in parameters.

With C#3.5

```
public static class ControlExtensions
{
  public static TResult InvokeEx<TControl, TResult>(this TControl control,
                                             Func<TControl, TResult> func)
    where TControl : Control
  {
    return control.InvokeRequired
            ? (TResult)control.Invoke(func, control)
            : func(control);
  }

  public static void InvokeEx<TControl>(this TControl control,
                                        Action<TControl> func)
    where TControl : Control
  {
    control.InvokeEx(c => { func(c); return c; });
  }

  public static void InvokeEx<TControl>(this TControl control, Action action)
    where TControl : Control
  {
    control.InvokeEx(c => action());
  }
}
```

Safely invoking code now becomes trivial.

```
this.InvokeEx(f => f.label1.Text = "Hello World");
this.InvokeEx(f => this.label1.Text = GetLabelText("HELLO_WORLD", var1));
this.InvokeEx(() => this.label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString());
```

---

With C#2.0 it becomes less trivial

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
  private delegate void UpdateControlTextCallback(Control control, string text);
  public void UpdateControlText(Control control, string text)
  {
    if (control.InvokeRequired)
    {
      control.Invoke(new UpdateControlTextCallback(UpdateControlText), control, text);
    }
    else
    {
      control.Text = text;
    }
  }
}
```

Using it simple, but you have to define more callbacks for more parameters.

```
this.UpdateControlText(label1, "Hello world");
```

Answer (score 8):

Some more possibilities:

```
this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => this.DoSomething(param1, param2)));
```

or

```
this.Invoke(new Action(() => this.DoSomething(param1, param2)));
```

or even

```
this.Invoke(new Func<YourType>(() => this.DoSomething(param1, param2)));
```

where the first option is the best one, because MethodInvoker is concepted for that purposes and has a better performance.

Answer (score 6):

As Luke says, use Control.Invoke like this...

For example in a form:

```
public delegate void DelegatePassMessages(string name, int value);

public DelegatePassMessages passMessage;
```

In the contructor:

```
passMessage = new DelegatePassMessages (this.MessagesIn);
```

Then the MessagesIn function to receive data:

```
public void MessagesIn(string name, int value)
{

}
```

Then to pass data to your form:

```
formName.Invoke(formName.passMessage, new Object[] { param1, param2});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think Samuel's (excellent) approach can be pushed even more:

**Extension Method:**

```
public static void ExecuteAsync<TControl>(this TControl control, Action action)
where TControl : Control
{
  new Thread(() =>
  {
    control.Invoke(action);
  })
  .Start();
}
```

**Form code:**

```
private void doStuff()
{
  this.ExecuteAsync(() =>
  {
    // Do your stuff in a separate thread
    // but having full access to local or instance variables.

    // No (visible) threading code needs to be used here.
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here ya go using lambda expressions with the Invoke() extension + an input parameter.

Using:   action(STARS db)

```
_ccb.GetImagerFRU_PartNbr().Invoke(new Action<STARS>(dbase => _ccb.GetImagerFRU_PartNbr().Text = dbase.PartNumber(serial) ?? String.Empty), db);
```

Answer (score 0):

Found an elegant method for .net 2.0 with anonymous methods wrapped in a MethodInvoker Delegate. That way is no need to define own delegates all the time. Example:

```
    private void InitUI(Guid id, string typename)
    {
        MethodInvoker inv = delegate{tvMatrix.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(id.ToString(), typename);};
        tvMatrix.Invoke(inv);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not

```
tvMatrix.Invoke((MethodInvoker) (() => {
    tvMatrix.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(id.ToString(), typename);
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void ppTrace(string tv)
    {
        if (_Txb1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            _Txb1.Invoke((Action<string>)ppTrace, tv);
        }
        else
        {
            _Txb1.AppendText(tv + Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
```