# Need to set more than just a single property during Control.Invoke

Tags: c#, invoke

I have been searching stackoverflow for ways to marshal data back from a thread to the UI thread, and have found various ways to do it in 3.5.

One of the more elegant solutions to me; although I am still learning lambdas and closures is this solution [Control.Invoke with input Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783925/control-invoke-with-input-parameters).

I don't completely understand the code, but I do understand how to use it and it doesn't quite solve my problem.

I would like to call invoke and pass a string to another method (DisplayStatusUpdate(msg)). Any pointers would be appreciated.

```
    private void FireEventAppender_OnMessageLogged(object sender, MessageLoggedEventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayStatusUpdate(e.LoggingEvent.RenderedMessage);
    }

    private void DisplayStatusUpdate(string text)
    {
         _StatusTextBox.Text = _StatusTextBox.Text + text;
         _StatusTextBox.Text = String.Format("{0}\r\n", _StatusTextBox.Text);
         _StatusTextBox.SelectionStart = _StatusTextBox.Text.Length - 1;
         _StatusTextBox.ScrollToCaret();
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with as many parameters as you like, for example:

```
private void FireEventAppender_OnMessageLogged(object sender, MessageLoggedEventArgs e)
{
    DisplayStatusUpdate(e.LoggingEvent.RenderedMessage);
}

private delegate void DisplayStatusUpdateDelegate(string text);

private void DisplayStatusUpdate(string text)
{
     if(InvokeRequired)
         this.Invoke(new DisplayStatusUpdateDelegate(DisplayStatusUpdate), text);
     else
     {
         _StatusTextBox.Text = _StatusTextBox.Text + text;
         _StatusTextBox.Text = String.Format("{0}\r\n", _StatusTextBox.Text);
         _StatusTextBox.SelectionStart = _StatusTextBox.Text.Length - 1;
         _StatusTextBox.ScrollToCaret();
     }
}
```

There is another method that I have been using in a current project that can reduct the code significantly.  Details are [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/AOPInvokeRequired.aspx).

If you implement this method, you would need to:

Create the form using the AOP factory:

```
Form f = AOPFactory.Create<Form1>();
Application.Run(f);
```

And then you just decorate the event handler with the [RunInUIThread] attribute.  It uses Castle's method interception model to automatically invoke if need be.

Thus, the above code becomes:

```
private void FireEventAppender_OnMessageLogged(object sender, MessageLoggedEventArgs e)
{
    _StatusTextBox.Text = _StatusTextBox.Text + text;
    _StatusTextBox.Text = String.Format("{0}\r\n", _StatusTextBox.Text);
    _StatusTextBox.SelectionStart = _StatusTextBox.Text.Length - 1;
    _StatusTextBox.ScrollToCaret();
}
```

Performance wise it seems to be comparable, slightly slower, but depending on what you are doing it may be ok, it definitely takes less code.

Comment: Nice, thank you Brandon.

I knew the signature was going to change a bit for DisplayStatusUpdate, but just couldn't nail it.

Comment: sorry, the signature is the same but you knew what I meant.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using C# 3.5 (or later) you can use captured variables, which may simplify the code:

```
private void DisplayStatusUpdate(string text)
{
    this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => 
    {
         _StatusTextBox.Text = _StatusTextBox.Text + text;
         _StatusTextBox.Text = String.Format("{0}\r\n", _StatusTextBox.Text);
         _StatusTextBox.SelectionStart = _StatusTextBox.Text.Length - 1;
         _StatusTextBox.ScrollToCaret();
    }));
}
```

What the compiler will do behind the scenes here is to generate a class to hold the text, create a [`MethodInvoker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.methodinvoker.aspx) delegate, and pass that delegate and an instance of the generated class to the `Invoke` method. In the above design this will of course do the unnecessary work of creating a delegate and calling Invoke even if the code is already running on the same thread; but I believe that a method like this should not be called that often that it would be a performance issue.

If you want to you can replace the use of MethodInvoker with the parameter-less [`Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx) delegate, or any other parameter-less delegate that returns `void`.