# Can't modify datagridview from task (c#)

Tags: c#, user-interface, delegates, task, invoke

My scenario:

I've declared (out of class) the delegate:

```
public delegate void add_row_item(string category, string name, string address, string locality, string cap, string tel, string fax, string www, string email_results, string business_url, string map_query, DataGridView table);
```

Then i've this function that add a rows to my datagridview on main form

```
 public void update_add_row_item(string category, string name, string address, string locality, string cap, string tel, string fax, string www, string email_results, string business_url, string map_query, DataGridView table)
        {
            table.Rows.Add(category, name, address, locality, cap, tel, fax, www, email_results, business_url, map_query);
        }
```

But when i invoke method in a task i get a "method name expected" error:

```
results_grid.Invoke(new add_row_item(update_add_row_item(category, name, address, locality, cap, tel, fax, www, email_results, business_url, map_query, results_grid)));
```

What's wrong in my code?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because when you initialize a delegate, it's expecting you to say which function you're pointing it to, not the entire function call itself.  So, you need to initialize the delegate, and then follow up the rest of the Invoke call with the parameters, like so:

```
results_grid.Invoke(new add_row_item(update_add_row_item), 
    category, name, address, locality, cap, tel, fax, www, email_results, business_url, map_query, results_grid
);
```

Also, look at this link for more information on different ways of doing this:

[Control.Invoke with input Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783925/control-invoke-with-input-parameters)

Comment: Love is always good; I'd settle for an accepted answer though. ;)