# TabPage: Image is removed upon text change

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

I'm currently trying to change the text of a specific TabPage with an image from an ImageList. But each time when I try to change the text of the TabPage, the image is removed.
Here's how looks:

[image: Before the text change]

[image: After changing the text]

Here's how I'm changing the text:

```
private void Log_UnreadChanged(int unread)
    {
        this.InvokeEx(f =>
        {
            if (unread > 0)
            {
                f.logTab.Text = "Log (" + unread + ")";
            }
            else
            {
                f.logTab.Text = "Log";
            }
        });
    }
```

The InvokeEx method is from [ControlExtensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783925/control-invoke-with-input-parameters).

Comment: Can you share the code where you initialize the tab header with text and image?

Comment: @KernelMode this is done in the designer code, should I share it anyways?

Comment: No. Can you search in your project the usages of `logTab.ImageIndex` and check if you see any unexpected assignments?

Comment: @KernelMode I'm using `ImageKey` and there are no other usages besides this one and the one in the designer code.

Comment: So use the index (`int`) instead of the key (`string`) and tell me what happens. I mean remove all `...ImageKey = ` in your code. I suspect you have the wrong key (`string`).

Comment: My designer generates **only** `ImageIndex = `. No `ImageKey= `.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that I was using the `ImageKey` Instead of the `ImageIndex` property. I got it to work by setting the `ImageIndex` after each text change.